# How to remove an event listener in Hammer.js 2.0 and bind the recognizer to a new function

Tags: javascript, dom-events, hammer.js

I am a bit confused on how to correctly remove an event listener in Hammer.js 2.0

Following the advice in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367198/hammer-js-cant-remove-event-listener) it seems I just need to use

`mc.off(eventString, functionEvent);`

However I can't seem to get this to work, when I have 2 functions which I need to call with the same recognizer. My example is I need someone to panleft, then I need to remove this listener and listen for another panleft.

As you can see in my simplified [codepen example](http://codepen.io/StevenIseki/pen/avBEPY) I try to call `mc.off` in the first function, then set up the next event, but it runs both simultaneously.

So what I want in my example is for the first `panleft` to trigger the first function, then the second `panleft` to trigger a new function

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('myElement');

var mc = new Hammer(myElement);

mc.on("panleft", function(ev) {
  selectFirst('first')
});

function selectFirst (text) {
    myElement.textContent = text;
    mc.off('panleft', selectFirst);

    mc.on("panleft", function(ev) {
      selectSecond('second')
    });
}

function selectSecond (text) {
    myElement.textContent = text;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367198/hammer-js-cant-remove-event-listener) I linked to above and its [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LSrgh/3/)

As was mentioned in that answer, you can fix the issue by not using an anonymous function.

`hammertime.on("touch", callback);`

However it didn't seem to fix my issue of trying to remove the initial function and bind to a new one with the same recognizer.

I ended up just adding a new element and binding this to the second function. I suggest the same as you probably should only have 1 `panleft` event for the element and if it needs to do something different just add another hammer element with the `panleft` on it.