# Hammer js - off() method doesn't work

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

I am using Hammer this way, it works (it just triggers next/prev buttons):

```
var slider = document.getElementsByClassName('slider');

Hammer(slider[0]).on("swiperight", function() {
    prev.click();
});
```

A according to [Stack thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427715/removing-hammer-events), on event when modal is coming out (hammer is still swiping behind it :/) I am trying to turn it of with:

```
Hammer(slider[0]).off("swipeleft");
Hammer(slider[0]).off("swiperight");
```

But it doesn't work. It's still swipeing behind modal. Any idea why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save the `Hammer` instance to a variable. The following example removes `pan` event after 5 seconds.

```js
var h = new Hammer(document);
  
h.on('pan', function(){
   console.log('Panned');
});

setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('removed');
    h.off('pan');
}, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="http://hammerjs.github.io/dist/hammer.min.js"></script>
```